# Renombrar carpetas con número total de archivos en su interior

Tags: javascript

El siguiente código para un botón de un explorador de archivos permite renombrar carpetas, insertándoles al final de su nombre, el número de archivos que estas contienen.

Ejemplo: Familia    >    Familia (18)

Pero me gustaría que se considerara no solo el número de archivos, sino también el de carpetas, es decir, que el número se refiera al número total de archivos (archivos + carpetas).

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject');

function OnGetNewName(getNewNameData) {
    if (!getNewNameData.item.is_dir) return;
    return getNewNameData.newname + ' (' + fso.GetFolder(getNewNameData.item).Files.count + ')';
}
```

Desde ya muchas gracias por cualquier ayuda!

Comment: @Cris223511.dev no eso es javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para obtener el número total de archivos (archivos + directorio) dentro de un directorio, necesitarás realizar un recorrido recursivo en el directorio y sus sub-directorios. Para ello, puedes utilizar una función recursiva que cuente los archivos y carpetas dentro de cada directorio y, finalmente, sume ambos valores para obtener el número total; tambien es posible controlar la recursividad de una funcion mediante un argumento/parametro

Ejemplo:

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject');

function getTotalFilesAndFoldersCount(folder, recursive) {
    var fileCount = 0;
    var folderCount = 0;
    var subFolders = new Enumerator(folder.SubFolders);
    var files = new Enumerator(folder.Files);

    for (; !subFolders.atEnd(); subFolders.moveNext()) {
        folderCount++;
        if (recursive) {
            var subFolder = subFolders.item();
            var counts = getTotalFilesAndFoldersCount(subFolder, true);
            fileCount += counts.fileCount;
            folderCount += counts.folderCount;
        }
    }

    for (; !files.atEnd(); files.moveNext()) {
        fileCount++;
    }

    return { fileCount: fileCount, folderCount: folderCount };
}

function OnGetNewName(getNewNameData, recursive) {
    if (!getNewNameData.item.is_dir) return;

    var folder = fso.GetFolder(getNewNameData.item);
    var counts = getTotalFilesAndFoldersCount(folder, recursive);

    return getNewNameData.newname + ' (' + (counts.fileCount + counts.folderCount) + ')';
}
```

La función ***getTotalFilesAndFoldersCount*** realiza un recorrido recursivo de todas los sub-directorios y archivos dentro del directorio proporcionada, contando el número total de archivos y carpetas. Luego, en la función ***OnGetNewName***, utilizamos esta función para obtener el recuento total y agregarlo al final del nombre de la carpeta.

para evaluar o no evaluar la recrusividad deberias usar algo asi:

```
// Para realizar una búsqueda recursiva (en subdirectorios):
var newName = OnGetNewName(getNewNameData, true);

// Para realizar una búsqueda solo en el directorio actual (no recursiva):
var newName = OnGetNewName(getNewNameData, false);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @ArcanisGK507 por el tiempo y la dedicación, el script funciona perfectamente, pero él considera el total absoluto de archivos y carpetas, y yo realmente solo necesito el total de archivos y carpetas en un primer nivel, en el nivel inmediato, no sé si me hice entender. Si pudiera modificar el script para obtener este resultado más limitado le agradecería tanto, y disculpa por tanta molestia, muchas gracias!!!

Comment: solo quitale la recurrencia entonces... la recurrencia es un siguiente nivel ... saludos

Comment: Disculpe mi ignorancia, pero la recurrencia sería cuál? El bloque que comienza con for... y termina con }, porque eliminé esa parte del código y solo cuenta los archivos, no las carpetas?!?

Comment: la recurencia es cuando llamas a la misma funcion desde dentro de ella, dejame actualizar la respuesta.

Comment: Demoré porque estaba estudiando los códigos, ellos funcionan perfectamente bien, el primero cuenta de forma recursiva y el segundo de forma no recursiva, pero quería hacerle una pregunta, ellos están configurados para contar el número de subcarpetas? Porque cuando renombro una carpeta que contiene un archivo y una subcapeta, el número incorporado a la carpeta es 1, cuando debería ser 2 ?!?

Comment: Cuenta items, asumo que debe ser subcarpetas y archivos, no tengo como testear esa parte, necesitas ignorar las carpetas?

Comment: No, todo lo contrario, quiero considerar las carpetas también. Imagina que tengo una carpeta con el nombre Anatomía, dentro de ella tengo 3 archivos (3 PDF) y una subcarpeta que contiene otros 2 archivos (2 tomos de un mismo libro), al final dentro de la carpeta Anatomía tengo 4 libros (3 archivos y 1 subcarpeta). Me gustaría que el script me renombrara la carpeta Anatomía como Atatomía (4) , de la forma que el script está solo cuenta los archivos, no las subcarpetas

Comment: ya lo probaste?

Comment: Sí, lo he probado varias veces, con archivos diferentes, PDF, mp3, etc., y el resultado es siempre el mismo, todo perfecto en el sentido de los archivos, pero ignora completamente las subcarpetas, no las cuenta. Por ejemplo, si intento renombrar una carpeta que en su raíz solo tiene subcarpetas, no archivos, me renombra la carpeta como (0)

Comment: intenta ahora ... a ver si con el ultimo cambio lo logramos

Comment: Ahora sí @ArcanisGK507, perfecto, mil veces gracias, no tengo como agradecerte, fuerte abrazo!!!

Comment: de nada para eso estamos.

Comment: Dios te ilumine siempre y te recompense por tan nobles intenciones

Comment: No quiero abusar de tu bondad @ArcanisGK507, pero trabajando anoche con tu script, tuve otra necesidad. Será muy difícil crear una versión del script que permita contar solo los archivos PDF y EPUB (no archivos de otro tipo, ni subcarpetas), y todo de forma NO recursiva?!?

Comment: eso es otra pregunta... sube la y por hay te tiran la mano.

Comment: Cierto, buena idea, muchas gracias!