# Contar archivos PDF y EPUB

Tags: javascript

El siguiente script permite renombrar las carpetas con el número de archivos en su interior (forma no recursiva).

Ejemplo: Anatomía > Anatomía (4)

Pero me gustaría que solo se contaran los archivos PDF y EPUB. Alguien podría ayudarme en ese sentido? Muchas gracias!

Autor: @ArcanisGK507

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject');

function getTotalFilesAndFoldersCount(folder, recursive) {
    var fileCount = 0;
    var folderCount = 0;
    var subFolders = new Enumerator(folder.SubFolders);
    var files = new Enumerator(folder.Files);

    for (; !subFolders.atEnd(); subFolders.moveNext()) {
        folderCount++;
        var subFolder = subFolders.item();
        if (recursive) {
            var counts = getTotalFilesAndFoldersCount(subFolder, false);
            fileCount += counts.fileCount;
            folderCount += counts.folderCount;
        }
    }

    for (; !files.atEnd(); files.moveNext()) {
        fileCount++;
    }

    return { fileCount: fileCount, folderCount: folderCount };
}

function OnGetNewName(getNewNameData, recursive) {
    if (!getNewNameData.item.is_dir) return;

    var folder = fso.GetFolder(getNewNameData.item);
    var counts = getTotalFilesAndFoldersCount(folder, recursive);

    return getNewNameData.newname + ' (' + counts.fileCount + ')';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola @Xavier espero no llegar muy tarde... esta será mi última respuesta en la comunidad, asique espero que sea de utilidad para ti y para cualquier otro que la encuentre:

Antes que nada es importante implementar algo que valide que se trate de un EPUB o PDF, basados en la anterior respuesta que te di: [Link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/600426/315134) le hare algunos ajustes al script para que te haga el filtro de tipo de archivo.

El script debe quedar así:

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject');

function isEpubOrPdfFile(file) {
    var extension = fso.GetExtensionName(file);
    return extension === 'epub' || extension === 'pdf';
}

function getTotalFilesAndFoldersCount(folder, recursive) {
    var fileCount = 0;
    var folderCount = 0;
    var subFolders = new Enumerator(folder.SubFolders);
    var files = new Enumerator(folder.Files);

    for (; !subFolders.atEnd(); subFolders.moveNext()) {
        folderCount++;
        if (recursive) {
            var subFolder = subFolders.item();
            var counts = getTotalFilesAndFoldersCount(subFolder, true);
            fileCount += counts.fileCount;
            folderCount += counts.folderCount;
        }
    }

    for (; !files.atEnd(); files.moveNext()) {
        var file = files.item();
        if (isEpubOrPdfFile(file)) {
            fileCount++;
        }
    }

    return { fileCount: fileCount, folderCount: folderCount };
}

function OnGetNewName(getNewNameData, recursive) {
    if (!getNewNameData.item.is_dir) return;

    var folder = fso.GetFolder(getNewNameData.item);
    var counts = getTotalFilesAndFoldersCount(folder, recursive);

    return getNewNameData.newname + ' (' + counts.fileCount + ')';
}
```

Comment: +1 Es verdad, el método `GetExtensionName` es una buena opción. Lo que no he probado es verificar si siempre devuelve el nombre de la extensión en minúsculas.

Comment: Hola ArcanisGK507, muchas gracias una vez más, el script perfecto como el anterior, estoy muy feliz por ello, y triste al mismo tiempo porque no contaremos más contigo en esta comunidad, pero tus razones tendrás, solo te deseo mucho éxito por donde quier que andes, fuerte abrazo!!!

Answer (score 2):

A la hora de contar los archivos necesitas verificar su extensión, así:

```js
var fso = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject');

function getTotalFilesAndFoldersCount(folder, recursive) {
    var fileCount = 0;
    var folderCount = 0;
    var subFolders = new Enumerator(folder.SubFolders);
    var files = new Enumerator(folder.Files);

    for (; !subFolders.atEnd(); subFolders.moveNext()) {
        folderCount++;
        var subFolder = subFolders.item();
        if (recursive) {
            var counts = getTotalFilesAndFoldersCount(subFolder, false);
            fileCount += counts.fileCount;
            folderCount += counts.folderCount;
        }
    }

    var fileName;
    var ext;
    for (; !files.atEnd(); files.moveNext()) {

      fileName = files.item().Name;

      // El nombre del archivo es demasiado corto
      if (fileName.length<4) continue;

      // Verificamos la extensión
      ext = fileName.substr(-4).toLowerCase();
      if (ext == '.pdf' || ext == 'epub') fileCount++;
    }

    return { fileCount: fileCount, folderCount: folderCount };
}

function OnGetNewName(getNewNameData, recursive) {
    if (!getNewNameData.item.is_dir) return;

    var folder = fso.GetFolder(getNewNameData.item);
    var counts = getTotalFilesAndFoldersCount(folder, recursive);

    return getNewNameData.newname + ' (' + counts.fileCount + ')';
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Marcos por tu respuesta, sé que en ella está la solución a mi problema, pero lamentablemente no he sabido insertar tu código, podría decirme, por favor, el número de línea en el cual debo insertarlo?!? Muchas gracias

Comment: @Marcos prefiero usar .GetExtensionName(file); es más acertado y seguro, si el archivo tiene varias extenciones o tienen algun nombre rado como que se va a romper ...

Comment: Hola @Xavier, he actualizado mi respuesta para darte un código completo. Espero te sirva. De paso, no dejes de revisar la respuesta de Arcanis. Saludos!

Comment: Hola @Marcos gracias una vez más, esta vez mandándome el código completo, pero lo he probado una y otra vez y siempre me genera error señalando la siguiente línea:  let fileName = files.item().Name; De todas formas te agradezco enormemente todo el esfuerzo!!!

Comment: @Xavier, actualice mi código. Espero ahora si te funcione. Saludos!

Comment: @Marcos, ahora no se genera error, pero no renombra las carpetas, pero si quieres no te preocupes con eso, ya con el código de ArcanisGK507 esta bueno, de igual forma te agradezco infinitamente!